# Server replication for Realm Mobile Platform

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm writing a mobile database application that needs to be capable of offline operation.  Realm Mobile Platform (developer edition) looks like an interesting possibility to simplify the back end.

However, I have a certification requirement to supply a live redundant server, and I see nothing in the Realm documents about server replication or high availability.  The database appears to be stored in a monolithic file, so I doubt I'd be safe trying to physically copy the live database.

Does this product support server replication or some other way to implement failover to a redundant server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, we are currently in beta. There are a number of features that we haven't been able to ship yet, but that are most definitely in the works and/or on our radar. Manual (snapshot) and continuous backup (live redundancy) is definitely part of this.

As you imagine, I can't commit to a firm timeline, as we have a fairly limited development team, and we're still going through all the feedback we've received since launch in order to figure out our priorities.

If you want, you can submit this as an issue in our bugtracker: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues

Comment: Thanks, it's useful to have your internal names for those features.  I've filed a bug.